# How to make a list of square numbers?

Tags: python

```py
count = 1
while count <= 100:
  print(count)
  count = (count + 1)*(count + 1)
```

This is what I've tried
It didn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by square list?

Comment: List of square numbers

Comment: Hello sujay, I feel like this question has definitely been answered before. There's a couple of things you should avoid with that code. Do not use a while for this, it can (and will) create an infinite loop in some cases. You're not incrementing your count, which means it will go on forever. You should probably make a list of numbers you want to square and then loop through that list with a "for number in number_list:" function. This loop will run exactly X times, where X is the amount of numbers in your list. This is a lot simpler and less dangerous to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment count by 1 each time, not square it. If you square it each time you don't know which is the next square number.

```
count = 1
while count <= 100:
  print(count * count)
  count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. Try the below code which creates a list using list comprehension and a for loop.

```
>>> res = [(count*count) for count in range(1,101)]
>>> print res
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `range` is faster and cleaner :

```
for i in range(101):
    print(i*i)
```

In this loop, you don't need to take care of the incrementation, it is automatically done by the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function.

Answer (score -1):

You first create an empty list like `list = []`
then append the value ... code will be as follow

```
list = []
count=1
while count <=100:
    squareNumber = count * count
    list.append(squareNumber )
    count = count +1
print(list)
```

Comment: If as asked in Question want to create list of square.